# Why $C^{\infty}(\Sigma, \mathbb{R}^D)$ instead of $\text{Emb}(\Sigma, \mathbb{R}^D)$ in string theory $\sigma$-model?

Tags: differential-geometry, string-theory, definition, conformal-field-theory, sigma-models

In most String Theory textbooks, e.g. Polchinski, Blumenhagen et. al., GSW, Becker & Schwarz, Zwiebach, the dynamics of the string is firstly motivated geometrically by the Nambu-Goto action $S_{NG} \propto \int_\Sigma \sqrt{\det{X^*\eta}}$, wheren $\Sigma$ is the worldsheet, $X: \Sigma \to \mathbb{R}^D$ is a map and $\eta$ is Minkowski metric on $\mathbb{R}^D$. To vary this action in a consistent manner, one need the pullback $X^*\eta$ to be non-degenerate (non-zero determinant). One can only guarantee this by imposing that the map must be at least an **embedding**.

The Polyakov's formalism consider that now the worldsheet has a Lorentzian metric $g$. The action of this formalism is $S_P \propto \int_\Sigma \sqrt{-\det g} g^{ab}\partial_a X^\mu \partial_b X^\nu$. The classical solutions to this action must be harmonic functions w.r.t. the metric $g$, assumed here to be Lorentzian $+$ the condition that $h \propto X^*\eta$. Since $h$ is a metric by assumption, the latter condition restricts the classical solution to be, again, an embedding. However, then performing a variation in the action $S_P$, we don't have the same problem in the action $S_{NG}$, since during the calculations the metric $h$ is independent of $X$.

At the classical level, string theory could be developed using $S_P$ and studying general smooth maps $X: \Sigma \to \mathbb{R}^D$, with the embedding restriction appearing only in the classical solutions. However, work with general smooth maps kills, I think, the geometric idea the maps $X$ originally had in the Nambu-Goto formulation, because they don't need to be bijective, or preserve topology, etc. They are simply smooth maps just to ensure that its components $X^\mu$ are smooth scalar fields on $\Sigma$. The worldsheet CFT and the euclidean path integral theory can be developed without any damage by this choice.

**Question**: Is this consideration on working with smooth maps $C^{\infty}(\Sigma, \mathbb{R}^D)$ instead of embeddings $\text{Emb}(\Sigma, \mathbb{R}^D)$ problematic in some way? I presume that the physicists that have worked on this topic for several years probably have a good reason to do so, but this reason is not clear to me.

Some places where one can find the approach considering only smooth maps are:

- [BV analysis of Polyakov and Nambu-Goto theories with boundary](https://arxiv.org/abs/2106.02983)
- [Polyakov action in nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Polyakov+action)
- [Nambu-Goto action in nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Nambu-Goto+action)
- Igor Dolgachev, p. 51 in: *Introduction to string theory for mathematicians* [[pdf]](https://dept.math.lsa.umich.edu/%7Eidolga/stringy.pdf)
- *Quantum Fields and Strings: A Course for Mathematicians Volume 2. 1999*

Comment: I'm not sure what to say about the merits of "embeddings vs $C^{\infty}$ maps", for the classical theory of a string, or even the quantum theory of a free string; but by the time you get to the case of physical interest, which is the quantum theory of interacting strings, there's no restriction to $C^{\infty}$ maps.

Comment: @MitchellPorter If not $C^\infty$ maps, what class of maps is used for a quantum theory of interacting strings?

Comment: Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/768958/2451

Comment: I just thought of it like any other path integral, that you include paths/surfaces/embeddings that are continuous but fractally spiky. I don't know if there's a best way to formalize it. The Scholarpedia article on path integrals talks about white noise being approximated by Gaussians. This may be e.g. what Polchinski does in "Evaluation of the One Loop String Path Integral"... Sorry for not having a clearer answer. But I don't think this is fundamentally different to any other path integral involving quantum fields.